# How to assign the data of table to the coordinates X and Y of a (qcc) plot with R (Rstudio)?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

I'm a newbie in R script, don't be too hard with me :).

So I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Day |Date       |Temperature    |Pression   |Flow
----|-----------|---------------|-----------|------
1   |5/10/2017  |85             |4          |100
2   |5/11/2017  |85             |4.5        |102
3   |5/12/2017  |88             |5.2        |103
4   |5/13/2017  |83             |4.1        |99 
..  |.....      |..             |...        |..
```

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfdXZ.png)

I do the necessary steps to import my CSV data.

I use a qcc function to do a Quality Control with Xbar.

I get my graph but the coordinates X and Y are inverted.
[Xbargrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfY9K.png)

I would like that in X coordinate that the values of the Date with the right format (no 17300 but 5-10-2017) and in Y with the coordinates Pressure.

I tried several but I can not: /

This is my program :

```
# Library
library(qcc)
library(readr)
library(Rserve)
Rserve(args = "--vanilla")

# Data column filter from CSV file imported
Test <- read_csv("C:/Users/..../Desktop/Test.csv", 
                 col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y")))


diams <- qcc.groups(Test$Date,Test$Pression)
#diams <- with(Test, qcc.groups(Day, Temperature))

#Background color
qcc.options(bg.margin = "white", bg.figure = "gray95")

#Xbar graph (means of a continuous process variable)
qcc(
    data = diams,
    type = "xbar",
    sizes = 5,
    title = "Sample X-bar Chart Title", # Replacement title
    digits = 2, # Limit the signifciant figures
    plot = TRUE)
```

Could you help me ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: try to learn to use data.table and ggplot2 package. If you use those.. then plotting dates also becomes more easy.

You can try this piece of code

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Use fread (fast-read) to get the csv
table = fread("C:/Users/..../Desktop/Test.csv")
# convert to date
table[,Date := as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y)]

#use ggplot to plot the a line
# aes stands for aesthetics
ggplot(data = table,aes(x = Date,y = Pression)) + geom_line()
# If you want to keep your lines.. you can add them with geom_vline()
```

Comment: Your program works but i would like to use the qcc plot with UCL an LCL limit.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot with Control Chart Lines can be achieved with the ggQC package

here are 2 examples with a simulation of your data set (plus a faceting bonus)

**Single Observation Per day**

```
#Simulate some data
df <- data.frame(
  "index" = 1:48,
  "date" = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2017-5-10"),
                    to = as.Date("2017-6-26" ), 
           by="1 day"),
  "pression" = rnorm(n=48, mean = 4.7, sd = .2)
)

require(ggQC)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=pression)) + 
   stat_QC(method = "XmR") + #draw the QC lines
   stat_QC_labels(method = "XmR") + # label the QC lines
   geom_point() + geom_line() # draw points and lines
```

**5 Observations per day**

```
#Make some data with group size = 5
df2 <- data.frame(
       "index" = 1:48*5,
       "date" = rep(
          seq.Date(from = as.Date("2017-5-10"),
                   to = as.Date("2017-6-26" ), 
                   by="1 day"),
          each = 5
          ),
      "pression" = rnorm(n=48*5, mean = 4.7, sd = .2)
       )

require(ggQC)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=date, y=pression)) + 
   geom_point(alpha=.3) + # show the individuals
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", color="black") + #show mean by day
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line", color="red") + #draw a line
   stat_QC() + # draw the qc lines
   stat_QC_labels() # write the labels on the lines
```

**Because its ggplot you can also do cool things like facet by month (e.g.)**

```
df2$month <- cut(df2$date, breaks = "1 month")
ggplot(df2, aes(x=date, y=pression)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=.3) + # show the individuals
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", color="black") + #show mean by day
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line", color="red") + #draw a line
  stat_QC() + # draw the qc lines
  stat_QC_labels() + # write the labels on the lines
  facet_grid(.~month, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Thank you Kgrey for your help, i succed to deblock some points, but i have an error on this code `df <- data.frame(Test,
                 Test$Date<- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2014-9-15"),
                    to = as.Date("2017-6-8"), 
                    by="1 month")
)`. This is the errror : `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Date, value = c(16328, 16358, 16389,  : 
  replacement has 33 rows, data has 871`

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax of your code. But the 33 rows comes from the 33 months between your date range. I think you want one of the following:

#Make the dates
df$Date<- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2014-9-15"), 
                    to = as.Date("2017-6-8"), 
                    by="1 day")
                  ) 
#or Cut the dates into months

df$month <- cut.Date(df$date, breaks = "1 month")

Comment: I found the solution here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801834/visualize-an-ggplot-according-to-a-precise-range-and-sampling-in-r/44804309#44804309). But I have with ggQC, i don't have the data of LCL and UCL on my graph.  This is the code : `date <- seq(from = valueDatemin, to = valueDatemax, by="1 day")
Test <- Test[Test$Date %in% date, ] 
...
p <- ggplot(Test, aes(x=Date, y=Temperature)) +
stat_QC_labels(method = "xBar.rBar") + # label the QC lines 
  stat_QC(method = "xBar.rBar") +geom_point() + geom_line() `

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the following graph
[image]

from the code below:

```
 set.seed(5557)
   df3 <- data.frame(
  "index" = 1:48,
  "date" = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2017-5-10"),
                    to = as.Date("2017-6-26" ), by="1 day"),
  "Temperature" = rnorm(n=48, mean=83, sd=5)
   )

   require(ggQC)
   require(ggplot2)
   ggplot(df3, aes(x=date, y=Temperature)) + 
     stat_QC(method = "XmR") + #draw the QC lines
     stat_QC_labels(method = "XmR") + # label the QC lines
     geom_point() + geom_line() # draw points and lines
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kgrey for you help. I have just one question, do you know how i can have the value UCL and LCL ? because with the fonction XmR_UCL() or XmR_UCL(). it doesn't work.

Comment: It's Ok, I found :`v_ucl <-xBar_one_UCL(Test$Temperature)`
`v_lcl <-xBar_one_LCL(Test$Temperature)`