# Visualize an ggplot according to a precise range and sampling in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have table as presented below:

```
 Day    |Date       |Temp1
    ----|-----------|---------------
    1   |9/15/2014  |85         
    2   |9/16/2014  |85          
    3   |9/17/2014  |88         
    4   |9/18/2014  |83            
    ..  |.....      |..          
    871 |6/8/2017   |98
```

I have a lot of data as Date columns 9/15/2014 until 6/8/2017. And I chose to take value all the 6 months for an ggplot clean.

This my code :

```
library(ggplot2)
#library(Rserve)
#Rserve(args = "--vanilla")

Test <- read_csv("C:/Users/..../Desktop/Myfile.csv")

valueDatemax <- max(Test$Date)

valueDatemin <- min(Test$Date)

# Simulate some data
df <- data.frame(Test,
                Test$Date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date(valueDatemin),
                to = as.Date(valueDatemax), 
                by="6 month"))

require(ggplot2)

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Test$Date, y=Temp1))

print(p)
```

But  I have an error that I don’t understand and I tried all solutions on net but I didn’t found.

this the error :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date, value = c(-719143, -718962, -718778,  : 
  replacement has 18 rows, data has 871
```

And i would like after to can choose my Date range , per example 30 last days.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you calling a variable in the dataframe `df` `Test$Date`? Just call it `Date`, and refer to it as such in your `aes` call.

Comment: I follow your advice in replacing  `Test$Date` by `Date`. But i have approximately the same error : `Error in data.frame(Test, Date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date(valueDatemin),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 871, 18`

Comment: Where is the error occuring? In the creation of `df` or when plotting? It's very difficult for anyone to help without having a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Date` is being recycled for the length of `Test`, which is causing your hangup.

Try subsetting your original dataframe, although I'm not sure where `Temp1` is coming from.

```
df <-Test[Date==seq.Date(from = as.Date(valueDatemin),
                                       to = as.Date(valueDatemax), 
                                       by="6 month"),]
require(ggplot2)

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Temp1))

print(p)
```

And if you want the last 30 rows

`tail(df,30)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a data import problem, not a plotting problem. Specifically:

1. You did not provide a small example of your CSV file. This makes it hard to know that your CSV file is actually correct and can be parsed as-expected by the functions you call. I will assume "Myfile.csv":

> Day, Date, Temp1
>
> 1, 9/15/2014, 85
>
> 2, 9/16/2014, 85
>
> 3, 9/17/2014, 88
>
> 4, 9/18/2014, 83
>
> 5, 9/19/2014, 83

2. There seem to be a missing dependency: the read_csv file is not in base R. Perhaps you meant readr::read_csv? I am assuming this for the rest of this post.
3. The critical point is that I see no code here that tells R that your second column is a date. Neither do I see information about how this date is formatted and should be parsed. Have a good look at the [readr vignette](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/09/readr-0-1-0/).
4. No need to use `seq.Date`, just make sure your data is of class "Date" and call `seq` on it.

The corrected code could look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

Test <- read_csv(
  "Myfile.csv",
  col_types=list(
    Day=col_integer(),
    Date=col_date("%m/%d/%Y"),
    Temp1=col_integer()
  )
)

print(class(Test$Date))  # a Date object as expected

valueDatemax <- max(Test$Date)
valueDatemin <- min(Test$Date)

date <- seq(from = valueDatemin, to = valueDatemax, by="2 days")
# TODO: change "by" as needed in the final code

Test <- Test[Test$Date %in% date, ] # keep only the desired dates

p <- ggplot(Test, aes(Date, Temp1)) + geom_point()
print(p)
```

[image]

**Note:** If you have the choice on how your dates are represented, choose a standard format, like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This will facilitate your task because readr will be able to automatically guess it is dealing with dates.

Comment: You have got a few answers now, @R.Bun. Please, mark one of them as solution or clarify your initial question.